# RSS feed of List View using [ME] returns view creator, not user

Tags: rss, list-view, outlook

I have created a list called "Phone Messages" with a People/Groups column called "Recipient", and a view that displays if the recipient is equal to [ME].  If I try to get an RSS feed from the view, it interprets [me] as the creator of the view (the administrator), not the user.  I know getting an RSS feed from a view is possible, so it's a problem with the [ME] tag and RSS that won't recognize the user.  The view on the site works properly, however.

Background: My office doesn't have answering machines, and messages are delivered on Post-It notes.  We've just started implementing MOSS 2007, and the users are reluctant to go to the SharePoint site.
I don't want to clog Outlook with everyone's messages.  This isn't a security issue (I know that using a view isn't secure), it's an attempt to get everyone using some of the services SharePoint provides.  Old habits, etc.

I'm looking for either a word-around for this problem (that doesn't include making a view for every single person), or at least an explanation for why the [ME] tag doesn't work for this.

Thanks for your time

Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ack!!! You are cheating on me!  I thought I was giving you the goods over here:

http://www.endusersharepoint.com/STP/viewtopic.php?t=1531&p=5661#p5661

I hope you get it in the end, whichever forum that may end up being on.

Comment: Sorry.  Got greedy.  Excellent help on endusersharepoint!